# Count character input using a single variable

Tags: c++, loops

1. I'm trying to count the input of characters, for example: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 10 10 10, but I can not get rid of the loop and start a new countdown.
2. When I try to record only the total number of cents on the screen, cout is always repeated in each cycle, how can I get only the whole amount at the end of the cycle?
3. How can I change my code to simplify the calculation of numbers?

Any suggestions?

```
int main(){
    int cent = 0;
    int cent_input = 0;
    int cent_quantity = 0;
    int downgrade_to_one = 0;

    do{
        while(true){
            cout << "\nEnter number: " && cin >> cent;
            switch(cent){
                case 1:
                     downgrade_to_one =  cent + downgrade_to_one;
                     if (cent == 0)
                     cent + 1;
                     cout << "\nYou have: " << downgrade_to_one << " one cent monets.";
                     break;

                case 2:
                     cent_input = (cent_input + cent) / cent;
                     cent_quantity = cent_quantity + cent_input;
                     cout << "\nYou have: " << cent_quantity << " two cent monets.";

                case 5:
                     cent_input = (cent_input + cent) / cent;
                     cent_quantity = cent_quantity + cent_input;
                     cout << "\nYou have: " << cent_quantity << " five cent monets.";
                     break;

                case 10:
                     cent_input = (cent_input + cent) / cent;
                     cent_quantity = cent_quantity + cent_input;
                     cout << "\nYou have: " << cent_quantity << " ten cent monets.";
                     break;

                case 25:
                     cent_input = (cent_input + cent) / cent;
                     cent_quantity = cent_quantity + cent_input;
                     cout << "\nYou have: " << cent_quantity << " twentyfive cent monets.";
                     break;

                case 50:
                     cent_input = (cent_input + cent) / cent;
                     cent_quantity = cent_quantity + cent_input;
                     cout << "\nYou have: " << cent_quantity << " fifty cent monets.";
                     break;

                default:
                    cout << "\nUndefined input!";
            }
        }
    }
    while(false);
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about which language you are using.  Notation such as `cout << "\nYou have: " << downgrade_to_one << " one cent monets.";` is C++, not C.

Comment: The double loop structure `do { while (true) {  … } } while (false);` is esoteric and novel, too.

Comment: after case 2: the break command is missing

Comment: The `&&` in `cout << "\nEnter number: " && cin >> cent;` performs a meaningless boolean AND. I suggest you get rid of it and put the `cout` and `cin` statements on separate lines.

Comment: @alterigel: The `&&` checks that the output succeeded — it won't try the input if the output stream is set into the fail state.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler technically true, but given the otherwise unchecked use of `cout` and lack of checks on `cin` and `cin.clear()` and the like, I really don't think that's what OP intended.

Comment: @alterigel — yes; since it doesn’t test that the input worked, it is mostly useless to test that the output prompt worked.

Comment: @f0xtr0d  Your comment flag has been declined. Please read about [how to flag comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, who downvoted my question. I solved this problem myself.

```
int main(){
int cent = 0;
int one_cent_amount = 0;
int two_cent_amount = 0;
int five_cent_amount = 0;
int ten_cent_amount = 0;
int twentyfive_cent_amount = 0;
int fifty_cent_amount = 0;
int cent_input = 0;
int cent_quantity = 1;
int dollars = 0;
int cents = 0;
int entire_quantity = 0;

cout << "\nEnter number: ";
while(cin >> cent){
switch(cent){
case 1:
if(cent == 0)
cent + 1;
one_cent_amount =  cent + one_cent_amount;
break;
case 2:
cent_input = (cent_input + cent) / cent;
two_cent_amount = two_cent_amount+ cent_input;
break;
case 5:
cent_input = (cent_input + cent) / cent;
five_cent_amount = five_cent_amount + cent_input;
break;
case 10:
cent_input = (cent_input + cent) / cent;
ten_cent_amount = ten_cent_amount + cent_input;
break;
case 25:
cent_input = (cent_input + cent) / cent;
twentyfive_cent_amount = twentyfive_cent_amount + cent_input;
break;
case 50:
cent_input = (cent_input + cent) / cent;
fifty_cent_amount = fifty_cent_amount + cent_input;
break;
default:
cout << "\nUndefined input!";
 }
                            scanf("%c", &cent); //%c to read a character
                if(cent == '\n') {
                            break;
        }
}
entire_quantity = one_cent_amount + (two_cent_amount * 2) + (five_cent_amount * 5) + (ten_cent_amount * 10)  + (twentyfive_cent_amount * 25) + (fifty_cent_amount * 50);
dollars = entire_quantity / 100;
cents = entire_quantity % 100;
if (entire_quantity != 1 && entire_quantity != 0)
cout << "\nYou have: " << one_cent_amount << " one cent monets."
              << '\n' << two_cent_amount << " two cent monets."
              << '\n' << five_cent_amount<< " five cent monets."
              << '\n' << ten_cent_amount << " ten cent monets."
              << '\n' << twentyfive_cent_amount << " twentyfive cent monets."
              << '\n' << fifty_cent_amount << " fifty cent monets."
              << '\n' << "Entire quantity: " << entire_quantity << " cents."
              << '\n' << "Your money are: " << dollars << " dollars and " << cents << " cents.";
else if (entire_quantity == 1)
cout << "\nYou have only " << entire_quantity << " cent.";
else if (entire_quantity == 0)
cout << "\nNothing is specified, you need to enter the amount!";
}
```